# Device policy manager is unable to set reset password token on Android ("Escrow token is disabled on the current user" exception is thrown)

Tags: android, device-admin

When attempting to set reset password token with [setResetPasswordToken()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setResetPasswordToken(android.content.ComponentName,%20byte[])) API following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Escrow token is disabled on the current user
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2005) ~[na:0.0]
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1951) ~[na:0.0]
at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.setResetPasswordToken(IDevicePolicyManager.java:8856) ~[na:0.0]
at android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager.setResetPasswordToken(DevicePolicyManager.java:2814) ~[na:0.0]
```

What is the meaning of this "Escrow token is disabled on the current user" message? I don't understand the reason behind the exception and I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. Did anyone also encounter this error and possibly has overcome it? Thanks in advance.

**Note:** This happened only once so far. In all other cases, *setResetPasswordToken()* works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, your app isn't set as Device Owner. (Using `dpm set-device-owner` command.)

As mentioned in [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#setResetPasswordToken(android.content.ComponentName,%20byte%5B%5D)):

> Throws:
>
> SecurityException  if admin is not a device or profile owner.

Comment: The strange thing here is that dpm set-device-owner command is issued programmatically prior calling setResetPasswordToken() method. This method is called on successful exit value of the command.